# ng-select prevent special characters on typeahead

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

Using the ng-select library, is is possible to prevent special characters from being processed? Something akin to [this](http://Controlar%20el%20ingreso%20de%20caracteres%20especiales%20de%20inicio,%20por%20ejemplo,%20espacios%20en%20blanco%20o%20arroba,%20o%20signos%20de%20puntuaci%C3%B3n.%20%20El%20unico%20caracter%20especial%20permitido%20es%20el%20guion%20y%20no%20de%20iniciio.) solution.

I've tried multiple approaches, but it seems like whatever the typeahead value is isn't exposed and can't be modified.

Is there any workaround to this? Even firing a `.next()` on the typeahead subject doesn't change what's shown on the view.

Comment: The link is not working for me. As a hint, ng-select is an onPush component so if you have to use in inbetween processing, you might have to manually do a changedetection to change the view..

Comment: @MikeOne what exactly on the view am I changing though? I don't see where the typeahead value is being stored

Comment: Please add a sample of what you want to do it is not clear from the question and the link you put in does not work.

Comment: Please fix the link in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you want to block special characters from being typed and you don't want to see them at all.

**Answer :**

Yes you can prevent special characters from being processed by using **keypress** event handler as shown below.

**HTML :**

```
<ng-select name="languages" (keypress)="blockSpecialChars($event)" placeholder="languages" [items]="suggestionsList" [typeahead]="typeahead" [(ngModel)]="currentValue" >
```

That's what you want : `(keypress)="blockSpecialChars($event)"`

Add into your **Typescript** :

```
  blockSpecialChars(event) {   
      var k;  
      k = event.charCode;
      return((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k == 32 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57)); 
  }
```

If you want to allow some special characters and you don't know what is there charCode. check it here : [KeyCode info](https://keycode.info/)

Answer (score 0):

By special characters, I assume you mean all non-numeric and non-alphabetic characters. In that case, you could strip the special characters before it is used for filtering using a simple regex like `searchTerm = searchTerm.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "");`.

A simple [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-typeahead-when-search-cleared-g9vnxk).

Template:

```
<h5>Select:</h5>
<ng-select [items]="items$ | async"
  bindLabel="name"
  bindValue="name"
  [closeOnSelect]="true"
  [multiple]="true"
  [hideSelected]="true"
  [typeahead]="input$">
</ng-select>
```

Component:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  public items$: Observable<Person[]>;
  public input$ = new Subject<string | null>();

  constructor() {
    this.input$.subscribe((typeahead) => {
      console.log(typeahead);
    });

    this.items$ = this.input$.pipe(
      map((term) => this.searchPeople(term))
    )
  }

  private searchPeople(term: string | null): Person[] {
    let searchTerm = term ? term : '';
    searchTerm = searchTerm.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "");
    return [
      { name: 'Jack Doe' },
      { name: 'Jonathan Hammond' },
      { name: 'Lindsay Johann' },
    ].filter((person) => {
      return person.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
    });
  }
}
```

Notice that only one empty space character is included (after `0-9`). So if there are more than one, the filter will fail and there will no suggestions.

**Example**:
Typing `jona!@#$%^&than hamm*}|"ond` would still suggest **Jonathan Hammond**. However, typing `jona!@#$%^ &than hamm*}|"ond` (notice space between ^ and &) wouldn't suggest anything.

Sample application forked from [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-typeahead-when-search-cleared).